# Create a Notification on the Icon of the application

Tags: blackberry, java-me

I want to create a red notification circle on the icon of the application when I receive something. Like in BBM, when a message is received, a red circle appears on the icon of the BBM. I want to do the same.

How to do that? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably, you are going to implement push notification or will call a method that checks the relevant service. After this implementation, you can use the [net.rim.blackberry.api.homescreen](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.5.0api/net/rim/blackberry/api/homescreen/HomeScreen.html) class like below;

```
Bitmap icon = Bitmap.getBitmapResource("newiconwithstar.png");
net.rim.blackberry.api.homescreen.HomeScreen.updateIcon(icon);
```